# Polymer dom-if what comes after the if?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a `demoMode` Boolean property for my element, and I want to display some dummy data when the property is `true` and live data when it's `false`.

I've tried:

```
<template dom-if if="{{_isDemo()}}">hello from demo</template>
<template dom-if if="{{_isLive()}}">hello from live</template>
```

where the functions are just `{return this.demoMode;}` and `{return !(this.demoMode);}`.

The live mode seems to always be showing no matter what. I tried using square brackets (`[[]]`), curly brackets (`{{}}`), and even no brackets (`if="_isDemo()"`). Do I need to use them?

The way it currently works is there's the app, and there's a `demo/index.html` that sends the `demo-mode` attribute like:

```
<my-app demo-mode></my-app>
```

(I'm open to other ways of doing this, if anyone has input!)

Comment: I noticed that my demoMode prop needed a default value of false. I also noticed that I can use if="{{!demoMode}}" I'm still unclear on the brackets/braces and functions though

Answer (score 3):

As @montrealist indicated, the `if` property should evaluate to a Boolean. The binding does not need to be a Boolean itself; it could also be a computed [binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed)/[property](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#define-a-computed-property) that returns a Boolean.

You're using a computed binding for the `if` condition, but the binding is missing a variable dependency (i.e., an argument), so it's evaluated only once at initialization. I assume `demoMode` has a falsy default value, which would cause `_isLive()` to always evalulate to `true`.

Since `_isDemo()` and `_isLive()` both depend on `this.demoMode`, your computed binding should be `_isDemo(demoMode)` and `_isLive(demoMode)`, respectively:

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      demoMode: {
        type: Boolean,
        value: false
      }
    },
    _isDemo: function(demo) {
      return demo;
    },
    _isLive: function(demo) {
      return !demo;
    },
    _toggleDemo: function() {
      this.demoMode = !this.demoMode;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.8.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <button on-tap="_toggleDemo">Toggle Demo Mode</button>
      <template is="dom-if" if="{{_isDemo(demoMode)}}">
        <h1>Demo Mode</h1>
      </template>
      <template is="dom-if" if="{{_isLive(demoMode)}}">
        <h1>Live Mode</h1>
      </template>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/EWPpzg?editors=1010)

> I tried using square brackets (`[[]]`), curly brackets (`{{}}`), and even no brackets (`if="_isDemo()"`). Do I need to use them?

Yes, you need them. Data bindings (including computed bindings) require the brackets (either square or curly). Normally, the curly brackets indicate a two-way data binding, while the square ones indicate one-way. For computed bindings, they both have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can pass a function into the `if`. The API [specifically mentions a boolean](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/dom-if). From doc:

> Elements can be conditionally stamped based on a **boolean property** by wrapping them in a custom HTMLTemplateElement type extension called dom-if

Just stick to properties. Also, your syntax may be based on an older version of Polymer. You need to declare the conditional template like so:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{demo}}">hello from demo!</template>
```

Here's a [working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8hxXNxK8hFlkRC81h8vo?p=preview) (all the logic is inside `name-tag.html`).